# Why F# class member is initialized every time it's called?

Tags: f#

I've tried to simplify the code. It is as follow.

```
type myClass() = 
    member this.Member1 = MyCSharpNameSpace.MyClass("param")

let myObj = myClass()
let myVal = myObj.Member1.MyMethod()
```

`MyClass` is a C# class. When ever I call the method of the member, it is re initialized. Because I tried the following to see if it does.

```
type myClass() = 
        member this.Member1 = 
                      printfn "Reinitializing"
                      MyCSharpNameSpace.MyClass("param")
```

Why does it do that? I thought after value is evaluated calling a function, the second time it's called the function is not evaluated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In F#, a member value is equivalent to a C# property with a getter.

i.e.

```
type MyClass() = 
    member this.Member1 = MyCSharpNameSpace.MyClass("param")
```

is equivalent to the C# code:

```
class MyClass
{
   public MyCSharpNameSpace.MyClass Member1 
   { 
       get { return new MyCSharpNameSpace.MyClass("param"); }
   }
}
```

Hopefully you can now see that every time that getter is called, a new instance of your C# class is going going to be created.

If you wish to initialise once when the class is constructed and then expose the created object, you could do it with an additional let binding, e.g.

```
type MyClass() = 
    let mem1 = MyCSharpNameSpace.MyClass("param")
    member this.Member1 = mem1
```

You could also use `member val`, which would automatically create a backing store:

```
type MyClass() = 
    member val Member1 = MyCSharpNameSpace.MyClass("param")
```

Comment: If I use member val instead of using let binding, would it be same thing?

Comment: @ozgur `member val` would automatically create a backing store, so that would also be a solution.